# How to make ORM (ActiveRecord) Models for union queries in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-postgresql, sql-view

I have an application that has some basic entities

Posts
posts have:

- Likes
- Comments
- and Ratings

I then have an SQL view to query for all three. With that I have a model called something like PostActivityView. A post has an activity view so I can call

`@post.activity_view`

which returns a collection of the appropriate values (from Likes, Comments, and Ratings). This all works correctly.

My issue is that this returns a collection of hashmaps, not Comments, Likes, and Ratings. This makes sense because my view is creating a new "with PostEvents as (...)" result. My question: is there a way to generalize these results and represent them with an ActiveRecord object?

Likes, Comments, and Ratings have different attributes so I do some aliasing in the view (comment's have comment.body for text and Ratings can have rating.comments for text so when needed I rename something like review.comments to .body). So my results all have the same attributes. It seems like I should be able to make an ActiveRecord object like PostEvent which just has the aliased columns. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do what you're describing. However ,do you really need to store them in separate tables? You could keep them all in a single table and use single table inheritance (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) to have separate classes (Likes, Comments, or Ratings) for each type of thing a particular row represents. Then the common stuff could sit up in the parent class, and the stuff specific to the more granular things could go into the descendant classes.

It sounds like your situation is the opposite of that and you're combining separate tables into a single union. I suspect that'd be very difficult to implement in ActiveRecord itself as different databases have different rules for how and when the contents of a database view may be modified (i.e., if you could somehow create an AR class that referenced your view the way you're proposing, what would happen when you call save?)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've gone down the path of providing a view to make it convenient to retrieve all of these objects in one set as a single type of object, when your requirement is really to bring back different objects.

Based on that I'd question the use of the view at all. I'm not anti-view you understand -- we use them quite a lot for producing read-only reports in our application for performance reasons -- but if you need the rows to be returned as their proper object type then I'd retrieve them separately as Likes, Comments, and Ratings.

Answer (score 0):

First solution would be to use the gem [scenic](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic) and create an `activity_views` view by using a union query:

```
create view activity_views
as (
select ...
from likes

union

select ...
from comments

union

select ...
from rating
)
```

your data need to be homogenous of course.